# pulseaudio microphone over network

Tags: networking, microphone, tunnel, pulseaudio

I have configured one X Terminal with Pulseaudio system wide and a client configured to use pulseaudio over network.

## At Pulseaudio server /etc/pulse/system.pa

load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.251.0/24

## At Pulseaudio client, /etc/pulse/default.pa

load-module module-tunnel-sink server=192.168.251.6:4713
load-module module-tunnel-source server=192.168.251.6:4713

The *client is playing sound at server* but the microphone is not working to send data to the client side.

Server (to sink)                <--- Client (OK)
Server (from source microphone) ---> Client (not working)

The configuration I am using is called direct connection. The only reference to use microphone was using Pulseaudio in Multicast/RTP configuration. Maybe this is the only way.

Please, any help or comment is very welcome.

Sincerely,
J. Ventura

Answer (score 0):

unless you have a local client 'recording' the microphone, it won't make it to the RTP sink as PA will suspend it for being idle. enable loopback of the mic to your local sinks with `load-module module-loopback ...` in `pulseaudio-server:/etc/pulse/default.pa`

after this, you'll get your microphone data reflected on the RTP stream.